# tangent plane for y^x at point (2,1)

Tags: linear-algebra

I test my answer using wolfram alpha pro but it  gets a different result to what I am getting. This is homework.

My result is z= 2(y-1)

partial derivative with respect to y is

```
   x.y^x-1
```

partial derivative with respect to x is 
       ln(y).y^x

ln(1) is zero, so the x term is zero, leaving 2^(2-1) = 2

so z = 2(y-1)

Comment: @Paul why is it z-1 ?

Comment: @Paul Okay I understand it now. z = f(x0,y0) which is 1^2 = 1. Is that correct ?

Comment: Not $z$ but $z_0=f(x_0,y_0)$. So you'd have to write your solution like $z-z_0 \equiv z-1 = 2 \cdot (y-1) \Leftrightarrow z = 2y - 1 $

Comment: is it saying the value of z0 is f(x,y) evaluated at x=0 and y=0

Comment: No, in your case $(x_0,y_0) = (2,1)$. $(x_0,y_0)$ stands for the particular point one considers. And $z_0 = f(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: if z=f(x,y) and f(x,y) =z=y^x then at the point (2,1) z is equal to 1 because z= (1)^2 = 1 I don't understand how that is not true ?

Comment: That is true. Where is the problem? But you stated in the comment above that $z_0=f(0,0)$ ("$z_0$ is $f(x,y)$ evaluated at $x=0$ and $y=0$"), which is just true if $(x_0,y_0) = (0,0)$, but in your case $(x_0,y_0) = (2,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tangent plane is defined as:

$$x_3 \equiv z \equiv t(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0) + \nabla f(x_0,y_0) \cdot (x-x_0, y-y_0)^T$$

Your derivation is correct, but you missed $ f(x_0,y_0) = 1$. So:

$$ x_3 \equiv z \equiv t(x,y) = 1 + 2 \cdot (y-1) = 2y - 1$$

and that's what Wolfram Alpha gives as well.

Answer (score 1):

The derivatives are correct, but left hand side for equation of tangent plane should be $z-z_0=z-1$.